# Python import statement doesn't work depending on position in __init__.py

Tags: python

Let's take a folder structure like this:

```
project_root
│   start.py
└───Application
    └───ViewModels
        │   __init__.py
        │   MagnifierWindowViewModel.py
        │   MainViewModel.py
        │   MainWindowViewModel.py
        │   PlotterWindowViewModel.py
```

These are the contents of the files:

> start.py

```
from Application.ViewModels import MainViewModel

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainViewModel = MainViewModel()
```

> Application\ViewModels\__init__.py

```
from Application.ViewModels.PlotterWindowViewModel import *
from Application.ViewModels.MagnifierWindowViewModel import *
from Application.ViewModels.MainViewModel import *
from Application.ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel import *
```

> Application\ViewModels\MagnifierWindowViewModel.py

```
class MagnifierWindowViewModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

> Application\ViewModels\MainViewModel.py

```
from Application.ViewModels import MagnifierWindowViewModel, MainWindowViewModel, PlotterWindowViewModel

class MainViewModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mainWindowVM = MainWindowViewModel()
        self.magnifierWindowVM = MagnifierWindowViewModel()
        self.plotterWindowVM = PlotterWindowViewModel()
```

> Application\ViewModels\MainWindowViewModel.py

```
class MainWindowViewModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

> Application\ViewModels\PlotterWindowViewModel.py

```
class PlotterWindowViewModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

With this structure, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project_root/start.py", line 4, in <module>
    mainViewModel = MainViewModel()
  File "project_root/Application/ViewModels/MainViewModel.py", line 5, in __init__
    self.mainWindowVM = MainWindowViewModel()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

But if I put the last line in `Application\ViewModels\__init__.py` first, the application runs just fine. Why is that?

The reason I have this `Application\ViewModels\__init__.py` is so that I can write

```
from Application.ViewModels import MagnifierWindowViewModel
```

instead of

```
from Application.ViewModels.MagnifierWindowViewModel import MagnifierWindowViewModel
```

Comment: Python isn't Java. You don't need to stick every class in its own file named the exact same thing as the class. Doing so is a *bad idea*.

Comment: And you should do `import *` unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I think you dropped a "not".

Comment: Yes, oops, I accidentally a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stuck every class in its own module named the exact same thing as the class. That's a *really bad idea* for the reasons you're seeing here: it is way too easy to get the class and the module mixed up.

When your `MainViewModel.py` performs its imports:

```
from Application.ViewModels import MagnifierWindowViewModel, MainWindowViewModel, PlotterWindowViewModel
```

what gets imported depends on how much of `Application\ViewModels\__init__.py` has executed. If this line has not executed:

```
from Application.ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel import *
```

then the import in `MainViewModel.py` imports the `MainWindowViewModel` module. If the `import *` *has* executed, then it shadows the `MainWindowViewModel` module with the `MainWindowViewModel` class defined inside the module, so the import in `MainViewModel.py` imports the `MainWindowViewModel` class.

Comment: So you're saying that imports in different files are processed asynchronously?

Comment: @CosminPolifronie: No. What imports execute first depends on how you order your imports in your code. You should try not to write code where the import order matters.

Comment: Ooooh, I see now. It's late. How would you structure this code so that situations like these are omitted? What would you do differently?

Comment: @CosminPolifronie: I would name modules in lowercase, following standard Python convention, which avoids confusing classes and modules. I would probably also use way less files - probably just one module for all the model classes shown here. Also, when using `import *` to expose the contents of multiple submodules in one package, I would still have the submodules import things from their actual location of definition, to avoid relying on `__init__.py` import order.

Comment: I've let some details out for simplicity. We're using PyQt as a framework, that's the reason we're using camelCase. We're also ușing a MVVM arhitecture because that's what felt natural for our project. There are 3 windows, each with its own MVVM, then a main VM that controls the rest and a main model (this is supposed to be an image processing framework, so we need a model for the images). The second reason is that multiple people are working on this using Git (so we need many files to avoid lots of merges). Knowing this, would you still recommend that?

Comment: @CosminPolifronie: Maybe not the part about using one module for all the model classes, depending on how complex your actual model classes are, but the recommendations regarding lowercase module names and submodule import styles stand.

Comment: I see. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "I would still have the submodules import things from their actual location of definition..."?

Comment: @CosminPolifronie: I would have the submodules import classes from the modules that actually define those classes, rather than from the parent package.

Comment: So you mean that I should use the style I've been trying to avoid (see the end of my initial post)?

Comment: @CosminPolifronie: You can use relative imports to save most of the typing.

Comment: It had more to do with the doubling of `MagnifierWindowViewModel` rather than the length of the import. We'll have to think about this.